# Is there a batch script to download the latest Craftbukkit Build?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

How can I write a batch script (Windows) that will download the latest Craftbukkit Build and put it in a certain directory whenever I run it?

So has anyone overcome the problem of updating Bukkit without a lot of hassle?

PS: Bonus points to anyone that can automatically update plugins too.

Comment: you'll need an application to do the actual download, like curl/wget on 'nix systems. and it should probably be on serverfault.

Comment: http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-rb/craftbukkit.jar is always latest recommended.

Comment: I know, but I like the dev builds better. However, is there really any difference between them?

Comment: dev builds are generated every night (though July the 4th seems missing, possibly it didn't successfully build), there is no guarantee it'll even run let alone the plugins will work (http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-dev/craftbukkit-dev.jar). These are then promote these to beta for testing when the feel like it, things are still likely to be broken, but it'll at least run (http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-beta/craftbukkit.jar). Finally after enough testing they promote these to recommended, for production servers this is recommended (http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-tb/craftbukkit.jar)

Comment: Thanks, seeing how nobody else answered this question, you could post this as an answer and I will accept it. Haven't had problems with the dev builds yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux I'm using `wget` and you can use it too even on Windows, try i.e. "complete package ..." from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Then write some batch file which you can call by Windows task scheduler (don't forget to `-O` wget parameter). For this automatic updating use only RB (recommended build), anyway you must restart your server. For plugins updating you can call `reload` from the server or restart again (see [this](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Installing_Plugins)).

Comment: btw. I'm using just my downloaders and applying plugins and server manually - for better control...

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a plugin if I recall correctly for that. Something like this: [Craft bukkit up to date.](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/craftbukkituptodate/)

The video here, has a Windows batch script for updating the server:[Auto update bukkit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-ajtAcApQI)

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. As for CraftBukkitUptoDate, I have tried thAt, but it does not work well with some batch scripts that I engineered. How about plugins?

Comment: pff, I don't think you can program that, I maybe can write a program that gets the latests version of bukkit, I will see. When its ready, I will let you know something, so you can use it ;).

Comment: Found something, its an autoupdater: https://code.google.com/p/panychulla-linux/source/browse/trunk/bukkit/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/updater/?r=77 but you will need to compile it.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, it should download a new version.